# Compass `_compass_list` usage

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to figure out how to turn a string into a list in Compass - this is not supported natively in SASS. For example the string `"a b c"` would become a list with a length of 3… essentially `[a, b, c]`, excepts lists aren't actually arrays.

The `_compass_list()` function appears to be exactly what I'm looking for according to the documentation: "Returns a list object from a value that was passed. This can be used to unpack a space separated list that got turned into a string by sass before it was passed to a mixin." However, in practice it simply wraps the string in a list (e.g. `"a b c"` becomes `["a b c"]`).

Looking at the source, it's obvious that's exactly what's happening. Perhaps it's a bug?
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/lists.rb#L47

Can anyone explain the proper use of this function to me?

Answer (score 0):

This function's code is identical to the next one's. The next one is said to return a single-element list.

Any advanced lists usage in SASS is a big PITA, unfortunately.

Maybe you could write your own Ruby-to-SASS function that parses a string and turns it into a list?